# How to remove a specific suggestion from Atom Editor autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

I deleted an attribute `attribute1` from a class.

Atom autocomplete keeps suggesting the text "attribute1" when I type "attribute", which leads to syntax errors.

How do I remove "attribute1" from the possible suggestions?

Comment: I primarily use Python, and it's even better in my case: whenever I type `None`, Atom proposes `none` instead. It's a default hint, so it's automatically changed when I hit enter to get to the new line. So annoying to have to press esc every time.

Answer (score 1):

If the suggestion is not a default suggestion, make sure you do not have the typo anywhere else in your currently open project, and then restart atom.

Answer (score 0):

Atom's autocompletion package reads words from opened files into runtime TextBuffer, futher uses it when autocompletion wanted.

To remove wrong suggestion from autompletion just remove it from files you have opened.